# Proof of a divergent sequence and convergent series

Tags: analysis

I was wondering if for a sequence $a_n$ and its series $ ‎\sum_{n=1}^{\infty‎}a_n$. If the sequence is divergent then is it true that the series must also be divergent and so the series can't converge. How might I show that this is true or false in general?

For instance, If I were to take a partial sum of the sequence and find that it diverges so it then doesn't make sense that the series converges as we will be either summing up "infinite" elements or the same elements. And if my partial sum is the whole sequence then by the same reason the series must also diverge right. So I think that this would be true in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If a series converges, then the sequence which defines the series is a null sequence.